# Meaning of negative stockholder equity

Tags: balance-sheet, equity, assets, liability, annual-report

In McDonald's 2016 annual report Balance Sheet, it shows `Total Liabilities is greater than Total Assets`. So it's `Total Stockholder's Equity` appears to be negative, with these fields reported as negative figures:

```
Accumulated other comprehensive income
Common stock in treasury
```

What is the meaning of these 2 fields? Does it indicate any unhealthy financial position when they are negative?